# What is the return value of request.args?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I am using request module of flask and trying to fetch arguments in the url by using `request.args` by using

```
req_args = { k:v[0] for k,v in dict(request.args).items() }
```

The `v` in the above code line turns out to be a list, whereas on my friends laptop it turns out to be a string.
Why is it so?

Comment: But even if it worked, that line would be pointless. You convert args to a dict, then loop through its items to... create a dict out of them. Why?

Comment: Sorry @DanielRoseman...it was v[0],that is the problem i have to use this thing to make it work whereas in some systems it works with this normal line req_args =dict(request.args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.args` type is `ImmutableMultiDict`, it is an immutable version of `MultiDict`. Here is the link you can click for more information about `ImmutableMultiDict`

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.args